# $\hat i\times\hat j$

Tags: vectors, cross-product

Very basic question ahead.

It is required to evaluate the cross product of $\hat i$ and $\hat j$, that is, $\hat i\times\hat j$. Knowing that the cross product is anti-commutative, I made sure to include these in the right order.

Now my work:

\begin{align}
\hat i\times\hat j &= (1, 0, 0)\times(0, 1, 0)&&\newline
&= \big((0)(0) - (0)(1), (0)(1) - (1)(0), (1)(0) - (1)(1) \big)&&\newline
&= (0, 0, -1)&&\newline
&= -\hat k
\end{align}

But "cheating" and exploiting the right-hand rule clearly shows that the correct answer is $+\hat k$. After trying multiple times, I'm wondering where I have gone wrong in my above process.

Comment: you applied the wrong formula. its 1x1 - 0x0 in the third coord

Comment: Which formula did you use for $(1,0,0)\times (0,1,0)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My rubric for computation of $\mathbf{x} \times \mathbf{y}$ is
$$
\left|\begin{array}z
& \mathbf{i}\quad\;\; \mathbf{j}\quad\;\;\mathbf{k}
\\
&x_1 \quad x_2 \quad x_3
\\
&y_1 \quad y_2 \quad y_3
\end{array}\right|
=
\left(x_2 y_3 - y_2 x_3\right)\mathbf{i}
+\left(x_3y_1-y_3x_1\right)\mathbf{j}
+\left(x_1y_2-y_1x_2\right)\mathbf{k}
$$
(The first is the "nonsense" version to help me remember the second one.)
Using this I get $\mathbf{i} \times \mathbf{j}= +\mathbf{k}$ .